# How to list all nodes on SGE cluster?

Tags: cluster-computing, sungridengine

I am trying to list all nodes on the cluster, but don't know the command. I searched if I use qhost it can list part of nodes. Any idea how to list all nodes?

Answer (score 16):

This can be done with the `qconf` command:

```
qconf -sh
```

Alternatively, depending on your configuration you may want:

```
qconf -sel
```

Comment: `qconf -sh` displays the Sun Grid Engine administrative host list ("nodes that submit jobs). `qconf -sel` displays the Sun Grid Engine execution host list (nodes that run jobs).